Rendering area between const plot and lines
I am encountering a bizarre rendering issue for this plot where the filled area appears to leave the area that it is bounded by.

Just wondering if anyone else is able to reproduce this error/suggest a fix.
It may be helpful to know that if I use const plot mark right this issue goes away, but the figure has the incorrect appearance.
My MWE is below:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% Define custom colors
\definecolor{CustomBlue}{rgb}{0.05882, 0.3725, 0.8392} % #0F95D7
\definecolor{CustomRed}{rgb}{0.8627, 0.1961, 0.1255} % #DC321F
\definecolor{CustomYellow}{rgb}{1, 0.7608, 0.0392} % #FFC20A

% Define default line width as a length
\newlength{\defaultlinewidth}
\setlength{\defaultlinewidth}{1pt}

% Apply default line width in PGFPlots
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={line width=\defaultlinewidth},
  every axis plot post/.append style={
    every mark/.append style={mark=*, mark size=1.2pt}
  }
}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\xmin}{0.382} % finding x for y = 5
\newcommand{\xmax}{4.25}
\newcommand{\ymax}{5}
\newcommand{\ymin}{0.098765} % finding y for x = 4.25

% Legend settings
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0.5,-0.05)},
anchor=north}} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    width=9cm,
    height=8cm,
    ticks=none,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel={$f_1$},
    ylabel={$f_2$},
    xlabel style={anchor=north}, % Move x-axis label below
    ylabel style={anchor=east}, % Adjust y-axis label position if needed
    xmin=-0.25, xmax=4.35,
    ymin=-0.25, ymax=5.25,
    domain=0:\xmax,
    restrict y to domain=-0.25:\ymax,
    samples=1000,
    unbounded coords=jump,
]

% Pareto Front.
\addplot+[no marks, color=CustomRed] {2/(x+0.25)^2};

% Place the reference point and show connection to PF
\addplot+[only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=red, scale=1.5}] coordinates {(\xmax,\ymax)};
\addplot[dashed] (\xmin, \ymax) -- (\xmax,\ymax); % horizontal
\addplot[dashed] (\xmax, \ymax) -- (\xmax,\ymin); % vertical

% Nearest front
\addplot+[name path = badfront, const plot mark left, color=CustomBlue, mark options={fill=CustomBlue}, samples at={1.025, 1.22, 1.35, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 3, 3.6}] {2.5/(x-0.5)};

% Calculate the y-value for the last mark
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lastMarkYValue}{2.5/(3.6-0.5)}

% Draw the last mark
\addplot+[only marks, color=CustomBlue, mark options={fill=CustomBlue}] coordinates {(3.6,\lastMarkYValue)};

% Draw a line from the last mark to the new point

% Repeat the above but for the first mark.
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstMarkYValue}{2.5/(1.025-0.5)}
\addplot+[only marks, color=CustomBlue, mark options={fill=CustomBlue}] coordinates {(3.6,\lastMarkYValue)};

% Shade the hypervolume

% Path defining the curve.
\addplot[name path = hvcurve, color=CustomRed] (1.025,\firstMarkYValue) -- (1.025,\ymax) -- ( \xmax, \ymax) -- ( \xmax, \lastMarkYValue) -- (3.6,\lastMarkYValue);

% Fill between the const plot and the upper line
\addplot fill between[of=badfront and hvcurve, 
   every segment no 0/.style={fill, color=CustomBlue!20}, area legend]; % Adjust the segment number as needed


% Single point to display HV improvement
\newcommand{\hvimpX}{2.6}
\newcommand{\hvimpY}{1.25}
\addplot+[only marks, color=CustomYellow, mark options={fill=CustomYellow}] coordinates {(\hvimpX,\hvimpY)};
% Shade HV improvement
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hvimpFrontY}{2.5/(2.0-0.5)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hvimpFrontX}{3}
\addplot[name path = hvimpcurve, color=CustomYellow, fill=CustomYellow!20] (\hvimpX,\hvimpY) -- (\hvimpX,\hvimpFrontY) -- ( \hvimpFrontX, \hvimpFrontY) -- ( \hvimpFrontX, \hvimpY) -- cycle;


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

The problem comes from the definition of your hvcurve curve which starts at the point (1.025,firstMarkYValue) and ends at the point (3.6,lastMarkYValue). Just reverse this path for the filling to be correct.
The correct path is this:
%% Path defining the curve.
\addplot[name path = hvcurve, color=CustomRed] (3.6,\lastMarkYValue) -| ( \xmax, \ymax) -|(1.025,\firstMarkYValue) ;

The Full Code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% Define custom colors
\definecolor{CustomBlue}{rgb}{0.05882, 0.3725, 0.8392} % #0F95D7
\definecolor{CustomRed}{rgb}{0.8627, 0.1961, 0.1255} % #DC321F
\definecolor{CustomYellow}{rgb}{1, 0.7608, 0.0392} % #FFC20A

% Define default line width as a length
\newlength{\defaultlinewidth}
\setlength{\defaultlinewidth}{1pt}

% Apply default line width in PGFPlots
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={line width=\defaultlinewidth},
  every axis plot post/.append style={
    every mark/.append style={mark=*, mark size=1.2pt}
  }
}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\xmin}{0.382} % finding x for y = 5
\newcommand{\xmax}{4.25}
\newcommand{\ymax}{5}
\newcommand{\ymin}{0.098765} % finding y for x = 4.25

% Legend settings
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0.5,-0.05)},
anchor=north}} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    width=9cm,
    height=8cm,
    ticks=none,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel={$f_1$},
    ylabel={$f_2$},
    xlabel style={anchor=north}, % Move x-axis label below
    ylabel style={anchor=east}, % Adjust y-axis label position if needed
    xmin=-0.25, xmax=4.35,
    ymin=-0.25, ymax=5.25,
    domain=0:\xmax,
    restrict y to domain=-0.25:\ymax,
    samples=1000,
    unbounded coords=jump,
]

% Pareto Front.
\addplot+[no marks, color=CustomRed] {2/(x+0.25)^2};

 Place the reference point and show connection to PF
\addplot+[only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=red, scale=1.5}] coordinates {(\xmax,\ymax)};
\addplot[dashed] (\xmin, \ymax) -- (\xmax,\ymax); % horizontal
\addplot[dashed] (\xmax, \ymax) -- (\xmax,\ymin); % vertical
%
% Nearest front
\addplot+[name path = badfront, const plot mark left, color=CustomBlue, mark options={fill=CustomBlue}, samples at={1.025, 1.22, 1.35, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 3, 3.6}] {2.5/(x-0.5)};

% Calculate the y-value for the last mark
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lastMarkYValue}{2.5/(3.6-0.5)}

%% Draw the last mark
\addplot+[only marks, color=CustomBlue, mark options={fill=CustomBlue}] coordinates {(3.6,\lastMarkYValue)};

% Draw a line from the last mark to the new point

% Repeat the above but for the first mark.
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstMarkYValue}{2.5/(1.025-0.5)}
\addplot+[only marks, color=CustomBlue, mark options={fill=CustomBlue}] coordinates {(3.6,\lastMarkYValue)};

%% Shade the hypervolume

%% Path defining the curve.
\addplot[name path = hvcurve, color=CustomRed] (3.6,\lastMarkYValue) -| ( \xmax, \ymax) -|(1.025,\firstMarkYValue) ;

% Fill between the const plot and the upper line
\addplot fill between[of=badfront and hvcurve, 
   every segment no 0/.style={fill, color=CustomBlue!20}, area legend]; % Adjust the segment number as needed


% Single point to display HV improvement
\newcommand{\hvimpX}{2.6}
\newcommand{\hvimpY}{1.25}
\addplot+[only marks, color=CustomYellow, mark options={fill=CustomYellow}] coordinates {(\hvimpX,\hvimpY)};
% Shade HV improvement
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hvimpFrontY}{2.5/(2.0-0.5)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hvimpFrontX}{3}
\addplot[name path = hvimpcurve, color=CustomYellow, fill=CustomYellow!20,fill opacity=.5] (\hvimpX,\hvimpY) -- (\hvimpX,\hvimpFrontY) -- ( \hvimpFrontX, \hvimpFrontY) -- ( \hvimpFrontX, \hvimpY) -- cycle;


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Like this:

Code (very short):
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \draw[-latex] (-1,0)--(8,0) node[below] () {$f_1$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-1)--(0,8) node[left] () {$f_2$};
        \draw[red,line width=3pt] plot[domain=.25:7.6,smooth,samples=103] (\x,{2/\x});
        \draw[blue,line width=3pt] plot[domain=.25:7.6] (\x,8);
        \shadedraw[top color=cyan,bottom color=blue,draw=none,opacity=.5] (.25,8) -- plot [domain=.25:7.6] (\x,{2/\x}) -- plot [domain=7.6:.25] (\x,8)-- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}

